# Add a new Column to my DataSet in spark Java API

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I'm new In Spark .
My DataSet contains two columns. I want to add the third that is the sum of the two columns.

My DataSet is:

```
+---------+-------------------+
|C1       |       C2          |
+---------+-------------------+
|   44    |                 10|
|   55    |                 10|
+---------+-------------------+
```

I want to obtain a DataSet like this:

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|C1       |       C2          |   C3    |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|   44    |                 10|   54    |
|   55    |                 10|   65    |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

Any help will be apprecieted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is:

```
df.withColumn("C3", df.col1("C1").plus(df.col("C2")));
```

or

```
df.selectExpr("*", "C1 + C2");
```

For more arithmetic operators check [Java-specific expression operators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) in the `Column` documentation.